# Can't use MyEclipse to create a Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

The error like the picture.And I try many ways by google but none of them can solve it.

I use myeclipse 2014 and maven is 3.3.3. the mvn -version is OK.

I have tried setting proxy, delete .m2/repository/ and some other ways.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is in the pom.xml ? Seems like a typical error you'd get when the pom is invalid in some way.

Comment: Did you also try the many ways by SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533885/could-not-calculate-build-plan-plugin-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378279/could-not-calculate-build-plan-artifact-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resource?

Comment: I couldn't see that problem when creating a maven project using the same archetype. Did you use a specific version of maven-archetype-webapp?

Answer (score 0):

I got the cause !! only because the network is not very well, and maven cannot download correctly